# Internet does not work with my Ubuntu 21.10 OS

Tags: wireless, internet

I have an unupdatedble 21.10 Ubuntu solo OS on my laptop. I can turn the laptop wifi on or off but when the wifi toggle is activated and the laptop does receive a good connected signal, the internet won't work. Everything on the device seems to be OK except there is no internet icon in the top right screen corner and obviously this is connected to the part to do with why the internet fails to work. How do I get that internet icon together with what ever else is missing, back working properly.
Ps. My only other devices are Android OS's and they work fine with the same wifi signal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry Pilot6 but I'm not sure what to edit in my question

Comment: Execute the terminal command that was mentioned in the comment, and copy both command and its output from the terminal into your question. Format that piece of text as code. Use "edit" to change your question.

Comment: I'm communicating here on separate a device. How do I copy the very long output of that command from my laptop onto my Andriod device. Can I ?

Comment: Sorry Martin but I can't see an answer to that question

Comment: You posted the same question a second time and didn't provide information to suggest a solution.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you are able to provide some diagnostic information. "How do I copy the very long output of that command from my laptop onto my Andriod device." Use a pencil and paper if necessary.